# Why I cannot control font size in HTML

Tags: html, css

I got this piece of code from W3 HTML website.

```
<header class="w3-container w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px" id="home">
    <h1 ><b>Hello</b></h1><br><br>
</header>
```

I know that this 'h1' was edited using w3 class. For my understanding, editing a tag inside the tag itself has more priority than the class edits. Anyway, I tried to change the `font-family` or `font-size` but that has no effect at all. This is what i did:

```
<header class="w3-container w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px" id="home">
    <h1 font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="800px"><b>Hello</b></h1><br><br>
</header>
```

Instead of 'h1' I used 'p' but still the same problem. When I used the tag`'font'` all my problems solved, but then I noticed 'font' tag has a line through and that is because it is not supported by HTML5. What should I do ? (I do not want to add css files)

Comment: No such attributes exist.  Learn about CSS.

Comment: `<h1 style="font-family:'Times New Roman';  font-size:800px">`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [inline-css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style):

```html
<header class="w3-container w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px" id="home">
    <h1 style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:800px"><b>Hello</b></h1><br><br>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are not putting the attributes in properly you havent wrapped the styles in a `style` attribute so your code can be fixed like so

```
<h1 style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size: 800px;"><b>Hello</b></h1><br><br>
```

can you see the difference between this and your original code?

```
 <h1 font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="800px"><b>Hello</b></h1><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="800px"><b>Hello</b></h1>
```

Should be:

```
<h1 style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:80px"><b>Hello</b></h1>
```

Notice how the styling is wrapped in `style=""`. This is required when doing styling this way.

[Check it out in action here.](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOUL1670PR74)